# How To Stick Buttons To The Screen Shen Scrolling

Tags: java, android, xml

This is my code of two buttons in xml file, I have tried lot but my buttons didn't stick to screen while scrolling.
There is a constraint layout at a parent, and inside it there is a card view and in this card view there are lots of things and two of them are buttons as a text view and I have given background of buttons to these two text view, I want to stick these two buttons to the screen and stick to the screen while user scrolling.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/add_cart_buy_now"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_8"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_16"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_8"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_8"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_8"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/horizontal_line"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_selling_price">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/add_to_cart"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_8"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_8"
                    android:background="@{isPharma ? @drawable/pharma_add_to_cart : @drawable/fashion_add_to_cart}"
                    android:onClick="@{(v) -> addClick.onIncrement(ivItemImage)}"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_16"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_8"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_16"
                    android:text="@{variant.quantity == 0 ? @string/add_to_cart : @string/go_to_cart}"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:visibility="@{variant.quantity >= 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
                    app:enableView="@{!(variant.getQuantity() >= variant.getStock())}"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/buy_now_1"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:background="@drawable/pharma_add_to_cart" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buy_now_1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_8"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_8"
                    android:background="@drawable/fashion_buy_now"
                    android:onClick="@{buyNow}"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_8"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_16"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_8"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_16"
                    android:text="@string/buy_now"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:visibility="@{(!isPharma || isFashion )  ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
                    app:enableView="@{!(variant.getQuantity() >= variant.getStock())}"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/add_to_cart"
                    app:layout_constraintT`enter code here`op_toTopOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Bring buttons out of scrollview

Comment: Share your whole xml file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.